# How to maintain real-time when using Spark's stateful operation updateStateByKey

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, apache-spark, spark-streaming

First the imaginary use case. Let's say I have a stream of tuples `(user_id, time_stamp, login_ip)`. I want to maintain the last login IP of each user at 5 seconds granularity.

Using Spark streaming, I can use the `updateStateByKey` method to update this map. The problem is, as the stream of data keeps coming, the RDD of each time interval is becoming larger and larger because more `user_ids` are seen.  After sometime, the map will become so large that maintaining it takes longer time, thus the real-time delivery of the result can not be achieved.

Note that this is just a simple example that I come up with to show the problem. Real problems could be more complicated and really need real-time delivery.

Any idea (In Spark as well as other solutions will all be good) on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not quite updating a `Map`. The function you give is just updating state associated to one key, and Spark is doing the rest. In particular it is maintaining a map-like `RDD` of key-state pairs for you -- really, a series of them, a `DStream`. So the storage and update of the state is distributed like everything else. If the update isn't fast enough, you can scale up by adding more workers.

Comment: Thanks Owen. Nice to see you answer the question. By `Map` I actually meant map-like `RDD`, sorry for the inaccuracy. Just started to learn Spark, and what I did not realize is that the storage of a `RDD` is also distributed and the states for different keys are updated concurrently. I'll play with the number of workers to see the result. Thanks.

Comment: over a period the state is growing.. and i get array out of bound exception.. at 30th min when i increased the workers to 2 i got the same exception at 40th min.. so at some point its going to grow how to overcome it?

Comment: @mithra Did you ever find the answer to your question on the mailing list? I'm curious as well. One of my solutions is to have a counter for each entry in this "map" and when the entry has not been updated in the passed K times I remove the entry by returning None in updateStateByKey.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to remove older ones, Spark should take care of that. Sean is correct, if you keep track of a lot of "keys" you need enough memory for all of them.